# Why does QGIS 2.0 print composer not render the legend names?

Tags: qgis-2, legend, print-composer

I made a map using the print composer in QGIS 2.0. However, in the legend it does not display the name of all the items listed. I have updated the legend items, removed the items and added them again but does not work. Also, if I add an image to the map it is not displayed (item send to front does not make a difference). 
Am I missing a setting or is it a bug?

[image]

Comment: Could you expand on "does not display the name of all the items listed"? I don't understand what that means. And what file format is the image?

Comment: Can you see the legend names in the normal view of qgis?